# What is the correct name for the ACTION you do when installing a jumper?

Tags: jumper

While writing an instruction document for configuring an evaluation board's firmware, involving the repeated installation and removal of jumpers, I used the terms "install", "connect" and "reconnect" to describe putting a jumper in place. I used the term "remove" for taking it out.

One of the reviewers thinks that "connect" is a wrong term, as it may confuse the user, as in "connect to what?".

So I was wondering, are there correct terms to describe these two actions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be most unambiguous to use "short pins x and y using jumper" or something similar? As for connect, you can turn that into connect pins using jumper. As for confusing a users, well as soon as you're using jumpers, you've eliminated lusers, and if your users are going to be configuring a board's firmware, they should at least be able to determine when you're telling them to use a jumper. Also you can use construction "connect jumper to pins X and Y" too.

Comment: I would just "put a jumper on pins x1 and x2", or whatever.

Comment: Are you talking only about jumpers on three pins also? I think of the kind that can have two positions a-b or b-c, while completely removing the jumper is not a normal use.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - it was a long time ago, but I think this one was specifically the two-pin type.

Answer (score 5):

If I were writing formally, I would probably speak of "installing a jumper".

If I were speaking informally, I'd probably talk about "strapping" or "jumpering" something.

Comment: well, "Please jumper jumper J1" sounds a little funny 8-)

Comment: Why not use the verb "jump"
Please jump jumper J1 ;D

Answer (score 3):

Install or insert are good. Connect is poor unless you specify pins as @AnrejaKo said.

Comment: Yes, I like "insert" more.

Comment: I don't.  Your not putting it *into* something as much as *on* something.

Answer (score 3):

I have usually seen "install" and "remove", and I think those are fine.  I'm assuming we're talking about sliding on the little black shorting blocks over two pins spaced .1" apart, right?

I don't like "insert" as much because you're not really putting the shorting block *into* something as much as *on to* someting.

I agree with your reviewer in not liking "connect".  Presumably these are instructions for non-technical users.  You shouldn't assume they know that the little black thingy makes a connection when installed, and that is a irrelevant implementation detail at the user interface level anyway.

Sometimes boards are designed so the same number of jumpers is always present.  This can be useful since non-electrical user won't have access to new jumpers when they need to add some.  In that case, jumpers are "moved" to one of the allowable positions: *Move the jumper at J1 to the A position*.  Or if you want to make it sound like a Japanese product so people won't even think of calling a support line: *Please to move jumper J1 honerable position A onto*

Comment: LOL, do you mean something like "All your base are belong to us"? You are right in your assumption - it is these little familiar jumpers. There are a couple of unrelated pin-pairs, they don't come in blocks, and are labeled J1, J2 etc. So I thought "install jumper J1" is a little too "heavy" - as we are not really *installing*, like in putting in a piece of the mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use "please **set** jumper XY", but be warned as English isn't my native language.

On [Jumper (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper_%28computing%29) I found

> Informally, technicians often call setting jumpers "strapping". To
>   adjust the SCSI ID jumpers on a hard drive, for example, is to "strap
>   it up".